# Create CLI tool in Groovy with Picocli

Tags: groovy, picocli

I am using Picocli with Groovy to create a CLI tool I followed the example here:
https://picocli.info/picocli-2.0-groovy-scripts-on-steroids.html

This example works well. 
But can't get a simple working example of multiple sub commands in Groovy. I want to execute it from the jar like:
 java -jar picapp -count [number of times] 
 java -jar picapp -names[List of name/s]

so:

```
java -jar picapp count 3 
outputs: 
hi, hi , hi

java -jar picapp names bob john
outputs:
hi bob
hi john
```

I guess I am trying to implement the functionality in a this format:
https://github.com/remkop/picocli/blob/master/picocli-examples/src/main/java/picocli/examples/subcommands/SubCmdsViaMethods.java

The Groovy code below doesn't compile:

```
@Grab('info.picocli:picocli:2.0.3')
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Model.CommandSpec;
import picocli.CommandLine.Parameters;
import picocli.CommandLine.ParameterException;
import picocli.CommandLine.Spec;
import java.util.Locale;
@Command(name = "hi", subcommands = { CommandLine.HelpCommand.class },
        description = "hi")

public class picapp implements Runnable {

    @Command(name = "count", description = "count")
    void country(@Parameters(arity = "1..*", paramLabel = "count",
            description = "count") int count) {
        count.times {
            println("hi $it...")
        }
    }
    @Command(name = "names", description = "names")
    void language(@Parameters(arity = "1..*", paramLabel = "names",
            description = "name") String[] names) {
        println 'CmdLineTool says \n\tWelcome:'
        names.each {
            println '\t\t' + it
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new ParameterException(spec.commandLine(), "Specify a subcommand");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(new SubCmdsViaMethods());
        if (args.length == 0) {
            cmd.usage(System.out);
        }
        else {
            cmd.execute(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code from your picapp.jar

Comment: Hi i haven't got the example with the jar building or even compiling in groovy i added a link with the structure I'm trying to achieve in Groovy rather than Java.

Comment: You have a working example and another example that shows how it works and now you want someone else to try it for you? Please add your code what you tried and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Comment: I added my attempt hope it helps as I said it doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you tried with a more recent version of picocli? Version 2.0.3 is very old and doesn’t support the `execute` method. Please try with version 4.1.4.

Comment: Thank you Remko @Grab('info.picocli:picocli-groovy:4.1.4') the code compiles and works fine!

Comment: The class is named `picapp` but should perhaps be named `SubCmdsViaMethods` since the `main` instantiates a `new SubCmdsViaMethods`. Also, the `run` method references `spec` but the class doesn’t define a `@Spec CommandLine.Model.CommandSpec spec` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that picocli version 2.0.3 is old and does not support the `execute` method. The `execute` method was introduced in picocli 4.0.

It is recommended to always use the latest picocli version. (Consider upgrading automatically with tools like [dependabot](https://dependabot.com/).)